# How to make my database invisible after decompile in android studio?

Tags: android, database

Decompile [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.msdict.embedded.wireless.oxford.dictionaryofenglish&hl=en) or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fast.dic.dict). You can't see the database(words, Synonym or ...). I wrote a dictionary app and my words are in the SQLite database. After decompiling the app, the person can see the database (words or ...).

How do I hide the database? Like ***Oxford Dictionary*** and other dictionaries?
Do these apps use SQLite?
Did I convey my mean clearly?

Comment: Download it at runtime in your private memory on first launch.

Comment: You can't. You'll need to store it online if you want that, but if you root a device, no APK and no file is safe.

Comment: @Nitesh if the device is rooted, app-private storage isn't actually private.

Comment: how these app work although device, not root? i want app work offline like these apps and device not need to root.  sorry if I say badly what I mean.

Comment: @Sajjadjavadi you don't root, but anyone who wants to access it and has a rooted device can find anything stored locally.

Comment: no such solution exists. If your app can decrypt it, then everyone can. The best thing you can do is obfuscate the dataset. Also: ask yourself... what are you hiding? Do you have illegal words in your database?

Comment: @ZUNJAE it's usually a problem related to proprietary software ("How do we protect our product?") rather than that. It's not easy hiding it though, it's relatively easy to decompile and reverse engineer after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want offline data, you have to encrypt your database. Use a database that you can encrypt, such as Sqlite. DB Browser for Sqlite will help you encrypt your database.

https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Or if you want an online database, then you have to use a backend such as Firebase or Amazon AWS.

Comment: I try this method. I set a password with DB Browser. now how to use SQLite? How to open encrypted SQLite to the android studio?

Comment: Even if encrypted, the password can be brute-forced with no restrictions when it's locally. Also, an encrypted database would most likely need the password stored in the app, which means it's relatively easy to unzip the apk and find the password (depending on storage, but I'm not entirely sure on that)

Comment: how to use SQLiteOpenHelper? it's not supported password.

Answer (score 0):

You have one option:

Store your words online (in Firebase for example) at first launch you download all the words and store it on SQLite (or Room database) and you are ready to go. By using remote server the download size of your apk also become smaller!

Comment: Yes it will work offline after you download the works, it is one time download!

Comment: Downloading makes it possible to find. And revealing a download link makes it easy to grab it too

Comment: @Zoe have you worked with Firebase? Take a read about it.

If using your own server you can obfuscate your link by adding it in resource!

Comment: Doesn't matter with a connection monitor. And it still doesn't change the fact that once it's downloaded, it can't be hidden

Comment: Obfuscation is not encryption. You cannot make something invisible by obfuscating it.

Comment: sorry! I don't know how to download the database from firebase to android studio. can you help me? I searched about firebase but all of them learned how to download an image.